# How to stop Random from generating everytime besides the first time?

Tags: java

Hello everyone I have this command:

```
for (z = 0; z < utenti.length; z++) {
    utenti[z] = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
}
```

After it's done generating random numbers between 1 and 1000 I want it to stop, the command is one of the functions in my program, but everytime i recall it the numbers generete randomly again. Is there a way to stop the random generation after the first time?

Comment: Why don't you just save the numbers into a variable?

Comment: This code must belong to a method in a class. Could you show us the relevant parts of that class also, especially the mentioned method and the `utenti` array?

Comment: Why do you have to recall it every time? Can't you simply use the `utenti[]` variable which has the numbers? It'll help if you explain your intention more clearly.

Comment: This command is part of an application I'm working, basically it's sort of bank functions, this one does the transfer, but before I do that I've set up so that the utenti[] (users) have a random amount of money between 1 and 1000, the transfer part and every other function works, I simply have a problem that everytime I recall a user, for example, user 10 has 10$, i transfer 20$ and it says he has 30, then when i do the whole function from start (the program doesn't end) the number is random again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop the random generation after the first time?

Yes.  Don't execute that code after the first time.  For example:

```
if (firstTime) {
    for (z = 0; z < utenti.length; z++) {
        utenti[z] = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
    }
    firstTime = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I you don't want to run the piece of code twice, then why are you calling it twice?

Since this piece of code is required to be executed just once, it probably is in the wrong place. It perhaps belongs in a constructor or something, depending on your program structure.

- You might just do what [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392663/507738), using a `boolean` to keep track of whether it's the first time or not. That might be the simplest option for you.
- In addition to the other answer, also note that one the constructors of the `Random` class accepts a seed. If you keep the seed the same, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers will be the same. This saves you the memory usage of the `utenti` array, especially with large arrays.

  ```
  private long seed;

  private void determineSeed() {
      long seed = new Random().nextLong();
  }
  ```

  And then use:

  ```
  Random rand = new Random(this.seed);
  for (int i = 0; i < utenti.length; i++) {
      int number = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1);
      // Don't save it to an array, do something with number
  }
  ```

  A drawback is that you cannot usage specific element of the sequence (for example, `utenti[i]`), you must use the random numbers in sequence.

Comment: But I actually need to recall a specific element. My array currently has 50 cells, if I need to recall a specific one, this code won't work then? Example: I recall user 30, he has 20$ randomly generated, i add 10$ so he has 30$, I recall the user 30 again and now he has another amount randomly generated instead of 30$ that he should have.